# php ajax multiple insert ı need

Tags: php, sql, ajax

```
            <div class="row">
                <?php 
                $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from is_ilanlari");       
                while($oku=mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
                {    
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <aside class="profile-nav alt">
                        <section class="card">
                            <div class="card-header user-header alt bg-dark" >
                                <div class="media">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="align-self-center rounded-circle mr-3" style="width:100px; height:100px;" alt="" src="images/korucanta.jpg">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h2 class="text-light display-6" style="size:10px;"><?php  echo $oku->is_ilanlari_baslik; ?></h2>
                                        <p>Görev süresi : <?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_bekleme_suresi; ?></p>
                                    <div class="h4 mb-0" style="float:right;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-money"></i><b> Para kazancı </b>
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary pull-right"> <?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_kazanc; ?></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa  fa-plus-circle"></i><b> XP kazancı  </b>
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right"><?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_bp; ?></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa  fa-clock-o"></i><b> Görev süresi</b>
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right" style="background-color:#35dccd; height:28px; text-color:white;">
                                    <p id="kutu1"><?php echo number_format($oku->is_ilanlari_bekleme_suresi); ?></p></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <form method="POST" id="degerler">
                                        <button type="button" name="buton<?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_id; ?>" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">KORUMAYA BAŞLA </button>
                                    </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var is_id = $(this).val();
        if(is_id!=""){
            $.ajax({
                url: "isbaslat.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    is_id: is_id        
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataResult){
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                    if(dataResult.statusCode==1){
                        //$("button").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('#degerler').find('input:text').val('');
                        $("#success").show();
                        $('#success').html('İş Başladı !'); 
                        console.log("b");
                    }
                    else if(dataResult.statusCode==0){
                       alert("Error occured !");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        else{
            alert('Please fill all the field !');
        }
    });
});
</script>

                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </section>
                    </aside>
                </div> 
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
```

this is form create php and ajax 
can you see ?

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include('baglanti.php');
include('fonksiyonlar.php');

    $kid=$_SESSION['kullanici_adi'];
    getir_kullanici($kid);  
    $k_id=$getir['kid'];

    $is_id=$_POST['is_id'];
    $sql = "insert into kullanici_is(is_ilan_id,kullanici_id,is_baslangic_tarih,is_durum) 
        values ('$is_id','$k_id','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."',1)";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>1));
    } 
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>0));
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

this is insert php you can see

http://prntscr.com/rhrmp5
ı want to insert a line.But this buttons all of them click and inserted 8 line in database.
How ı can insert just clicked value.
ı tryed all things pls help me

ı try again but no ı can t do it pls help me ı need more help . ı am waiting for

Comment: Please show the PHP used to create the forms and also the PHP used to handle the submitted data.

Comment: can you control again ?

Comment: check your network tab/XHR in developer tools, if you see 8 requests, then your selector is wrong, use a class as selector ,  and then on click event , this.val will give that specific value

Comment: You are giving all of your buttons the same id.  All elements must have unique ids.  There is a good chance that this is the problem.

Comment: All elements must have unique ids.Yes ı now.ı can take id this
 var is_id = $(this).val();
but ajax coming 8 times because ı have 8 job ı have 8 button how ı can insert this unique ids ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue: **code inside loop**
Solution: **move js code outside loop to avoid multiple instances,**

use a class for all buttons

```
$('.btn_class').on('click', function() {
 // now only the specific  btn is clicked
    $(this).val(); // will be of the clicked btn
     ...
 }
```

add btn class

```
 <form method="POST" id="degerler">
     <button type="button" name="buton<?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_id; ?>" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block btn_class">KORUMAYA BAŞLA </button>
 </form>
```

**fixed :**

```
     <div class="row">
                <?php 
                $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from is_ilanlari");       
                while($oku=mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
                {    
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <aside class="profile-nav alt">
                        <section class="card">
                            <div class="card-header user-header alt bg-dark" >
                                <div class="media">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="align-self-center rounded-circle mr-3" style="width:100px; height:100px;" alt="" src="images/korucanta.jpg">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h2 class="text-light display-6" style="size:10px;"><?php  echo $oku->is_ilanlari_baslik; ?></h2>
                                        <p>Görev süresi : <?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_bekleme_suresi; ?></p>
                                    <div class="h4 mb-0" style="float:right;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-money"></i><b> Para kazancı </b>
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary pull-right"> <?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_kazanc; ?></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa  fa-plus-circle"></i><b> XP kazancı  </b>
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right"><?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_bp; ?></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa  fa-clock-o"></i><b> Görev süresi</b>
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right" style="background-color:#35dccd; height:28px; text-color:white;">
                                    <p id="kutu1"><?php echo number_format($oku->is_ilanlari_bekleme_suresi); ?></p></span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <form method="POST" id="degerler">
                                        <button type="button" name="buton<?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $oku->is_ilanlari_id; ?>" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">KORUMAYA BAŞLA </button>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </section>
                    </aside>
                </div> 
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
 // move script outside the loop
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var is_id = $(this).val();
        if(is_id!=""){
            $.ajax({
                url: "isbaslat.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    is_id: is_id        
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataResult){
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                    if(dataResult.statusCode==1){
                        //$("button").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('#degerler').find('input:text').val('');
                        $("#success").show();
                        $('#success').html('İş Başladı !'); 
                        console.log("b");
                    }
                    else if(dataResult.statusCode==0){
                       alert("Error occured !");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        else{
            alert('Please fill all the field !');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's no different than doing `$('button').on('click' ...`

Comment: you should move your js code outside the loop, then it will work. i just noticed, your function is inside loop, which makes it 8 times, so it triggers 8 times on one click

Comment: when you want to have a dynamic or general function , for like  8 buttons but same action, you only need one instance of that function.

Comment: @AhmedSunny my eyes :( sory :) ı see it.Thank you my friend solved :)

Comment: @AhmedSunny  You should change the code in the answer to reflect the actual solution

Comment: ı am new where is ?

Comment: on the top left of my answer you see vote count, there is a tick mark, click on tick and up arrow